# How to create a simple tabbedpanels where a user can retain at current tab after refresh or updates - jquery,php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

how do you retain a current tab after (refresh, submit or jump menu) using jQuery WITHOUT cookies. because most of my friends (which are my clients) disable cookies on their terminal. Assume jQuery has been downloaded. I'm using php, javascript, html, sql and jQuery for my website. A clear explanation and an easy example is very well appreciated without using server sidescripts. And one more thing, please don't provide links as answers. I have already browse the Internet for few days, most of the examples are for intermediate and advance level. and most of the example are not from scratch and don't emphasize more on tabs. tq.

Comment: if you don't want to use cookies then perhaps `sessionStorage` might be the solution.

Comment: Use [localStorage](https://github.com/Script47/.js/tree/master/LocalStorage)?

Comment: yes. exactly RamRaider. tq. My friend's don't allow cookies on their terminals. So using sessionstorage would be an alternative. Could you kindly show an example? from scratch. Because most of the examples on the Internet have not yet emphasize basically on tabs, especially on retaining current tabs after updates, refresh etc.

Comment: The logic is simple, you save the name or index (a number which represents the tab), then when the page loads if it exists in your data storage then you display the tab which the user wants. You could use if-elseif-else or a switch statement.

Comment: Is there anybody out there generous or kind enough to help out here????

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: HI, @RamRaider. I made some small modification on your codes to see how it works. But the thing won't trigger. Please bear with me. Coz im in the learning process. <form action="#">
    <h1>Tabs & sessionStorage</h1>
    <div id='tabs'>
        <div id='t1'>tab 1</div>
        <p>Hi, this is the first tab.</p>
        <div id='t2'>tab 2</div>
          <p>This is the 2nd tab.</p>
        <div id='t3'>tab 3</div>
        <p>This is the 3rd tab.</p>
        <div id='t4'>tab 4</div>
        <p>This is the 4th tab.</p>
    </div>
</form>

Answer (score 0):

`sessionStorage` & `localStorage` are ideal to solve this sort of issue when cookies are not enabled. They are very easy to use and why you, as a developer, were unable to figure how to implement a system such as this. The code below is very basic and there is no jQuery involved ~ there might be some really easy to use methods built into jQuery but I don't know.

```
<form action="#">
    <h1>Tabs & sessionStorage</h1>
    <div id='tabs'>
        <div id='t1'>tab 1</div>
        <div id='t2'>tab 2</div>
        <div id='t3'>tab 3</div>
        <div id='t4'>tab 4</div>
    </div>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    /* The name of the storage Item */
    var store='tabs';

    /* a class name used to identify active tab */
    var cn='active';

    /* current value of the storage item, if any */
    var cval=sessionStorage.getItem( store );

    /* A nodelist of tabs within container */
    var col=document.querySelectorAll('div#tabs > div');

    /* Iterate through nodelist */
    for( var n in col )if( col[n].nodeType==1 ){

        /* assign click event handler */
        col[ n ].onclick=function(event){
            /* get reference to current node ( tab ) */
            var el=typeof( event.target )!='undefined' ? event.target : event.srcElement;

            /* set the value into storage item */
            sessionStorage.setItem( store, el.id );

            /* assign class to active and remove from inactive nodes */
            for( var m in col ){
                if( col[m].nodeType==1 ){
                    if( col[m].id==el.id )col[m].classList.add( cn );
                    else col[m].classList.remove( cn );
                }
            }
        }

        /* on load, assign active class to the correct tab */
        if( cval!=null && cval==col[n].id ) col[n].classList.add( cn );
    }
</script>
```

A rough demo that you will need to adapt and improve ( same javascript ) - it should be noted that the `form` is not important ~ it was merely for my purposes so you can omit it from the html and change the css. The important thing for you to understand is the way in which you can store and retrieve items from `sessionStorage` based upon events - the html given is very rough and ready - as you posted absolutely no code nobody can guide you with the layout - hopefully this will get you started.

```
<style>
    form > #tabs{
        width:80%;
        height:180px;
        display:block;
        margin:0 auto;
        float:none;
        box-sizing:content-box;
        padding:1rem;
        border:1px solid black; 
    }
    form > #tabs > div{
        width:20%;
        margin:0;
        float:left;
        clear:none;
        background:whitesmoke;
        text-align:center;
        box-sizing:content-box;
        border:1px solid black;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    form > #tabs > div:before{
        display:block;
        content:attr(data-title);   
    }
    form > #tabs > div:hover{
        background:#39F;
        color:white;    
    }
    form > #tabs > div.active{
        background:#9F0;
        border-left:none;
        border-bottom:none;
        border-right:none;
    }
    form > #tabs > div:first-of-type.active{
        border-left:1px solid black;
    }
    form > #tabs > div:last-of-type.active{
        border-right:1px solid black;
    }
    form > #tabs > div section{
        display:none;
        height:130px;
        width:600px;
        z-index:2;
        top:50px;
        text-align:left;
        padding:1rem;
    }
    form > #tabs > div.active section{
        display:block;
        background:white;
        color:black;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
</style>


<form action="#">
    <h1>Tabs & sessionStorage</h1>
    <div id='tabs'>
        <div id='t1' data-title='Tab 1'>
            <section><p>Aliquam dapibus convallis volutpat. Vestibulum urna lacus, tempor vel diam nec, viverra gravida est. Integer pharetra tincidunt nisi, ut egestas neque porttitor ut. Quisque ut consequat erat, a accumsan ligula. Maecenas ut placerat nunc. Aliquam finibus ligula ac ex hendrerit, quis blandit sapien sollicitudin. Donec ac velit quis sapien gravida efficitur efficitur eu purus. Etiam non risus mattis, consequat diam in, commodo tellus. </p></section>
        </div>
        <div id='t2' data-title='Tab 2'>
            <section><p>Aliquam dapibus convallis volutpat. Vestibulum urna lacus, tempor vel diam nec, viverra gravida est. Integer pharetra tincidunt nisi, ut egestas neque porttitor ut. Quisque ut consequat erat, a accumsan ligula. Maecenas ut placerat nunc. Aliquam finibus ligula ac ex hendrerit, quis blandit sapien sollicitudin. Donec ac velit quis sapien gravida efficitur efficitur eu purus. Etiam non risus mattis, consequat diam in, commodo tellus. </p></section>
        </div>
        <div id='t3' data-title='Tab 3'>
            <section><p>Aliquam dapibus convallis volutpat. Vestibulum urna lacus, tempor vel diam nec, viverra gravida est. Integer pharetra tincidunt nisi, ut egestas neque porttitor ut. Quisque ut consequat erat, a accumsan ligula. Maecenas ut placerat nunc. Aliquam finibus ligula ac ex hendrerit, quis blandit sapien sollicitudin. Donec ac velit quis sapien gravida efficitur efficitur eu purus. Etiam non risus mattis, consequat diam in, commodo tellus. </p></section>
        </div>
        <div id='t4' data-title='Tab 4'>
            <section><p>Aliquam dapibus convallis volutpat. Vestibulum urna lacus, tempor vel diam nec, viverra gravida est. Integer pharetra tincidunt nisi, ut egestas neque porttitor ut. Quisque ut consequat erat, a accumsan ligula. Maecenas ut placerat nunc. Aliquam finibus ligula ac ex hendrerit, quis blandit sapien sollicitudin. Donec ac velit quis sapien gravida efficitur efficitur eu purus. Etiam non risus mattis, consequat diam in, commodo tellus. </p></section>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: tq RamRaider.. tq so much.. I will study your answer and apply to my web. I will let you know tomorrow morning coz currently im very occupied with certain things right now. tq again. btw, the reason i cannot figure out the logic because im not professional as you. im a newbie actually in PHP.